# Linux Thread Scheduling

Tags: c, pthreads, embedded-linux, scheduling

I have one process on an embedded linux system that is running multiple threads (pthreads). All threads are type SCHED_FIFO.

For simplicity sake - Say that thread T60 has priority 60, T40 has priority 40, and T10 has priority 10. Each thread has a printf in it so I can kind of see who is running and when.

T60 psuedo code:

```
while(1)
{
  sendmsg();
  printf("T60 pending");
  fflush(stdout);
  pend_for_reply();
  printf("T60 got reply");
  fflush(stdout);
  process reply();
}
```

T40 psuedo code:

```
...
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  printf("T40 executing for loop\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  NoStallFoo();
}
```

T10 psuedo code:

```
while(1)
{
  wdog_pet();
  printf("T10 Running\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  sleep(2);
}
```

I would expect that because of the priorities i would NEVER see T10 output inside a block of 100 T40s. However what I'm seeing looks more like:
T60 pending
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
...
T40 executing for loop
T10 Running
T60 got reply
T60 pending
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
T40 executing for loop
....so on and so forth.

Clearly T40 has work to do, but somehow lower priority T10 is able to run. Can someone explain?

Comment: I would expect fflush to do sched_yield

Comment: Is the kernel compiled with realtime support? Does the machine have multiple CPU cores? Does the system support the priority levels you are using? How about a [MCVE]?

Comment: @stark - even if sched_yield is produced from a fflush, the higher priority should still run (from man page: If the calling thread is the only thread in the highest priority list at that time, it will continue to run after a call to sched_yield().)

Comment: @EOF - Its a huge project, the example would be tough to make but i will work on one. Its linux kernel 2.6.38 compiles with # CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY is not set
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y but no CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT patch

Answer (score 0):

in the scheduling algorithm,

at each cycle through the list of processes that are ready to run,

the process priority is decremented at each cycle through the list,

until the process actually runs,

then its' priority is reset back to the original priority